# How do I give box shadow to a <div> element or <hr /> element where the shadow fades out from the middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been given a UI design and I am asked to recreate it in React.js with sass/css.
Attached picture is a portion of the sidebar from the UI design. As you can see there is a box shadow effect beneath the selected option from the sidebar, where the shadow kind of starts to fade out from the middle.

I am assuming it can be done by putting the shadow effect under a `<hr/>` element or the `<div>` element itself. I have the icons position and spacing done, I just need the shadow part implemented.

How do I gain a shadow effect like this?

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

[image: Portion of a sidebar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is what you're looking for.

Using z-index:-1, we can position the pseudo element below its parent and using the 4th parameter for box-shadow, we can increase its extent. Tweak the numbers to get your desired result.

```css
.shadow
{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.shadow::after
{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and if I can get the desired effect using your idea then I will mark yours as correct answer.